# Exiting block of code when variable changes in python

Tags: python

I run into problem where I need to exit block of code when var changes to False.
e.g

```
...
var = True
var, msg = somefunction1(x)
var, msg = somefunction2(y)
var, msg = somefunction3(z)
...
```

somefunction* can return True or False. Is there are any way without adding if statement after each line to exit this block when var becomes False?

P.S. there are lots of functions and their names differ.

Comment: Why cannot you use `if` statements?

Comment: I guess it's because you have a lot of `var, msg = function` calls. Do the parameters change for all the function calls? If they don't, you could just iterate through them. ;-)

Comment: because in my specific case there are hundreds of these lines..

Comment: What about using `while` loop  ? `while var is not False: ...`

Comment: I need to run these lines one time. While loop would check after all this block is executed if var is not changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having to guess a little bit because I'm missing some context in your example, but you could use a list of functions and a loop? (this still involves an if, because the alternative is messier)

```
functions = [somefunction1, somefunction2, somefunction3]

for func in functions:
    var, msg = func()
    if not var:
        break
```

Something like that?

But I mean, if you *really* hate if statements:

```
functions = [somefunction1, somefunction2, somefunction3]

i = 0
var = True

while var and i < len(functions):
    var, msg = func()
    i += 1
```

Based on the update, and an unwillingness to write the functions directly into a list, you could (but shouldn't - seriously, just list the functions) do something like this (this assumes that all of the functions are called with no arguments, change the argcount check to the expected arguments if not):

```
functions = [x for x in globals().values()
             if hasattr(x, '__call__') and 
                hasattr(x, "__code__") and 
                x.__code__.co_argcount == 0]

for func in functions:
    try:
        var, msg = func()
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        continue

    if not isinstance(var, bool) or not isinstance(msg, str):
        continue

    if not var:
        break
```

You could rewrite that first line, but i'm undecided which version is less offensive/safe:

```
functions = [x for x in globals()["functions"]
             if  x.__code__.co_argcount == 0]
```

But to reiterate - just because you can do this, doesn't mean you should. I mean look at it, its an abomination.

Comment: Hahahaha. 16 seconds! :-P

Comment: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: Abomination ? :)) the first word which came to my mind whern i read your solution :D

Comment: @LexyStardust To get back to my question , I thought maybe there is some simple magical few lines method or exception to do this which is unknown for me in python :( ..

Comment: Well, I mean, my code works I think. Other than listing each of your functions I can't think of another way. I am wondering about your design though, perhaps there's a way of organising your code which would do away with this requirement?

Comment: I understand that , but as you said it is not very pretty :)) Ahh, I have just completed doing with if after each.
Now , random thought came, maybe I could have done it with wrapper.. +1 for good thoughts :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may help you, although that depends on how you call all the functions (in this case, there are no parameters).

```
functions = [f0, f1, f2, ...]
for f in functions:
    var, msg = f()
    if not var:
        break
```

Comment: Agh! I was 15 seconds too late! Love the fact that our answers are syntactically identical - " There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: @LexyStardust: it's because I wrote `fx` while you wrote `somefunctionx`. ;-P

Comment: Hmm, maybe you have idea how to put all functions to a list if there is many of them?

Comment: I could do that manually but it would take all most the same as putting if after each line. Any thoughts about putting it into try except block and raise if some value is changed?

Comment: @Dambre: that would be another questions, but there are many ways of automating that task. I would use Bash.

Comment: @Dambre - do all of your functions have the same naming convention? You could do some really awful (but functional) stuff using 'reflection' (not sure if that's what we usually call it in Python) and regex. But... seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: @LexyStardust right question. No they are different , it was just an example :/